# Can I play multiplayer on two consoles with game from the same account?

Tags: ps4, psn

My brother shared with me his PSN account and set my console as primary to allow me to play his games. Sometimes I play games from his PSN account, but I'm logged on to my PSN account all the time.
A few days ago he suggested playing co-op in one of his games.

Is it possible to play co-op in game which was bought only on his account? Or maybe is it possible to play the same game by both of us but everybody on his own PSN account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if you try to log into the same PSN account on a different PS4 while online, it will kick the other login off. You will both need your own copies of the game.

If you play on your own accounts, it should be fine. The PS4 should simply check that you are allowed to play the game, which by your brother making your console his primary, it should.